# How to login the website using soapui

Tags: soapui

I am testing the payment application. The procedure is

1. first run the payment webservice call..
2. Initiate payment response will return login url.
3. Take the url from the response and launch it in browser
4. Enter the user name and password.
5. Select login. it will navigate to next screen (say screen 2)
6. Here i need to pass cvc and select confirm

Till 3rd step it is working. But i am using HTTP request on the 4th step. But the username and password are not passed on the request and i don't know how to resolve it.

It would be easy for me if any one could help me out this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

```
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")

    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"))

    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Cheese!")

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    element.submit()

    // Check the title of the page
    log.info("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle())

    // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
    // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!")
        }
    });

    // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
    log.info("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle())

    //Close the browser
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is the soultion for me: problem description: I would like to call a website at backend, which was able to response for me with a JSON. The task was to test the JSON structure. I was not able to do it, because I always got a redirect for my login site.

solution: 1. Go to the "Show Service Viewer" and hit the "Service Endpoints" bar. Enter the http domain and the corrent username and password. For example, I would call `"http://www.rocket.com/backend /homescreenJson"` than I enter `"endpont"="http://www.rocket.com` and my username/pass for the site as I would login from the browser. 2.Hit the File/Preferencies in soapUI, go to the "HTTP settings" and check in the following box: "Add authentication setting to outgoing requests".

It worked for me. Cheers, Karoly